# Docker build fails on mkdir

Tags: image, ubuntu, docker, apache2

I use a Dockerfile to create an apache2 ubuntu image. When it haves to create the directories it fails saying that some of these directories already exists, but in fact not at all.
Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
    MAINTAINER Bernard Tapis
    RUN apt-get -yqq update && apt-get install -yqq apache2

WORKDIR /var/www/html

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
RUN mkdir p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2"]
CMD ["-D", "FOREGROUND"]
EXPOSE 80
```

The error I get when executing `docker image build -t quentinneves/apache .`

```
Step 11/14 : RUN mkdir p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR
 ---> Running in 1d72a8fd64c0
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/log/apache2': File exists
The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

But when I use `ls -lsa /var/log/` :

```
root@VIR1-DOCKER:~/Docker/Apache# ls -lsa /var/log/
total 1576
  4 drwxr-xr-x  5 root root   4096 Jun  1 13:42 .
  4 drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 Jun  1 13:35 ..
 16 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  13515 Jun 13 07:33 alternatives.log
  4 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Jun 13 07:33 apt
 12 -rw-r-----  1 root adm    8773 Jun  6 15:17 auth.log
  4 -rw-------  1 root utmp    768 Jun  6 07:06 btmp
 76 -rw-r-----  1 root adm   70771 Jun 13 08:05 daemon.log
108 -rw-r-----  1 root adm  107936 Jun  6 07:05 debug
268 -rw-r--r--  1 root root 269141 Jun 13 07:33 dpkg.log
  8 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  32032 Jun  6 07:05 faillog
  4 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root   4096 Jun  1 13:39 installer
356 -rw-r-----  1 root adm  363005 Jun 13 08:05 kern.log
 12 -rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp 292292 Jun  6 15:09 lastlog
252 -rw-r-----  1 root adm  255033 Jun 13 08:05 messages
428 -rw-r-----  1 root adm  435499 Jun 13 08:05 syslog
  4 drwxr-x---  2 root adm    4096 Jun  6 07:01 unattended-upgrades
 16 -rw-rw-r--  1 root utmp  15744 Jun  6 15:10 wtmp
```

Surprise it's not there ! Before that it was `/var/lock/apache2` that caused this issue, but it somehow passed and now `/var/log/apache2` just won't be created.

If I delete this folder creation and create it manually, would it works for creating a new image for docker ? And do you know why it thinks that there's already a folder like that ?

Comment: Why don't try with `RUN mkdir -p ...`. I think maybe you've missed '-' symbol just before 'p', unless you want to create `p` directory.

Comment: Other thing you can try is add at the end an `exit 0` clause, although it's not very pretty, it should work: `RUN mkdir p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR; exit 0`

Comment: @mulg0r : It's docker that execute this based on the Dockerfile

Comment: I know, but if build fails, maybe you're checking a container started from another image. Please, do a `docker container prune` and `docker image prune`, create again image with my indications and check your directory. Let's see

Comment: Sorry I missread this line, effectively it was the missing `-` that caused only one out of 3 folders to fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're creating directories without protecting against already-existence of them.

You've defined APACHE_LOG_DIR = APACHE_RUN_DIR, so, your `RUN mkdir p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR` command try to create it twice and it fails.

When you check directory existence, probably you're accesing a container started from another image different than you've tried to build with this docker.

To protect that, add `exit 0` at the end of `RUN mkdir`, or change one ENV:

```
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2   <--- the same than APACHE_LOG_DIR
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
RUN mkdir -p $APACHE_RUN_DIR $APACHE_LOCK_DIR $APACHE_LOG_DIR; exit 0
```

Comment: Well, this Dockerfile was given by my teacher and I copied without taking the time to analyze it. In this case the missing `-` was causing the issue, but it's good to know there's a workaround to progress in exercices.